# How to add class or ID to button without class or ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me to add class or ID to button in list (button have no class or ID at the moment).

I'm adding a button to my list element, using:

```
 $("#cat13").append("<button>expnd</button>");
```

But how to add a class or ID to that newly created button?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$("#cat13").append("<button class="yourClass">expnd</button>");`

Comment: why dont you set it while adding the button HTML?

Comment: I dunno. Now when I see answers I ask myself the same question.

Comment: ok...never mind. you must be working under pressure...!

Comment: @vijayP what? must be in loo...

Comment: Why do you need an id or a class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("#cat13").append("<button id='myButton' class='buttons'>expnd</button>");
```

Or

```
$("<button>expnd</button>")
    .attr("id", "myButton")
    .addClass("buttons")
    .appendTo($("#cat13"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the `id` and/or `class` are coming from a variable, and so you don't want to just put them in the HTML you're passing `append`.

You can supply attributes as a second argument to [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes):

```
$("#cat13").append($("<button>", {
    text: "expnd",
    id: "the-id",
    class: "the-class"
}));
```

Note we had to specify the contents of the button via `text`; `$()` can't handle it if we pass it anything but just a simple element.

Also note that if you have to support IE8 or other obsolete browsers, you'll need to put `class` in quotes: `"class": "the-class"`. For anything vaguely modern, you don't; using keywords without quotes in that context was allowed in the December 2009 ECMAScript 5th edition spec ("ES5").

Example:

```js
$("#cat13").append($("<button>", {
  text: "expnd",
  id: "the-id",
  class: "the-class"
}));
```

```html
<div id="cat13"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Or just turn things around:

```
$("<button>expnd</button>")
    .attr("id", "the-id")
    .addClass("the-class")
    .appendTo("#cat13");
```

Example:

```js
$("<button>expnd</button>")
    .attr("id", "the-id")
    .addClass("the-class")
    .appendTo("#cat13");
```

```html
<div id="cat13"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was about to suggest your first suggestion too, but I couldn't get it to work. Did you tried it ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: I'm going quietly mad here. I was doing a snippet for it, and it isn't applying those. But jQuery's done that since v1.4! Trying to figure out now what's going on.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: Figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to whatever you do in normal HTML.

`$("#cat13").append("<button id='my_id' class='my_class'>expnd</button>");`